# Can I uninstall visual studio 2017 and still use the 2017 platform toolset in visual studio 2019?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-2019

IIRC, you used to have to have a prior version installed in order to build using that tool set, but from what I gather now the platform tools are optionally installed with the newer version.  At the time I installed 2019, I was using the 2017 version, I still have lots of projects using the 2017 platform tool set even though I only use vs2019.

So my question is if I can now uninstall VS2017 and continue to build using that platform toolkit in VS2019?

TIA!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can, but not the way you think. The vc141 toolkit (VS2017) also comes with 2019 and you have to install it separately.

- uninstall VS2017 completely
- open the Visual Studio Installer
- click "modify" on the 2019 instance
- go to "invidual components"
- enter "v141" in the search field
- install all components you need

IOW: The platform and toolkit for VS2017 are *also* contained in VS2019.

Now you can choose "v141" in the "Toolkit" property and you can even mix and match.

Comment: BTW, if you can, you should install and try VS 2022 instead of VS2019. You can use both, VS2017 compilers and VS2019 compilers with VS 2022. The method to install them is similar. The VS 2022 IDE has lot's of improvement you will like.